# Upgrade/downgrade quotes in Textmate

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

Let's say I have this text:

```
"stringy thingy"
```

Is there a Textmate command or bundle that lets me place my cursor inside the quotes, press a command key sequence, and it will automatically change this pair of quotes back and forth between

```
"stringy thingy"
'stringy thingy'
```

Bonus points if there's a command or bundle that also works the same but between braces, parenthesis, and/or curly braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the source bundle, you have the **Toggle Single / Double String Quotes** command, it's mapped to <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>.